# How do I create a X mesh for my figure?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, geometry

So I'm designing an Model and wan't an X for its mouth. I created them by alligning 2 Cylinders. The Problem now is that it looks exactly that. One Cylinder that was placed on the other.. How can I combine the geometry so it forms an clean X shape?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can go in *Edit* mode, select one of your 2 meshes, and header menu *> Face > Intersect (Boolean)*.

You can also do it this way: If it needs to be cylindrical, what you can do is create a cylinder, scale it on Z and give it a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

Activate the *Bisect* on X, move and rotate the cylinder mesh in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Also activate the mirror *Axis* and *Bisect* on Z:

[image]

When you're good, apply the modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with the ***Skin* modifier** for an organic look.

[image: final shape]

- merge all vertices of the default cube at the center (<kbd>M</kbd> in *Edit* mode) to create a single vertex
- extrude 4 vertices (<kbd>E</kbd>) to create a X. Make sure you have not created  duplicated vertices (<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*)

[image: X vertices]

- add the *Skin* modifier. In *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you can control the thickness of the selected vertices. If it looks weird then select one vert and mark it as `Root` in the modifier's settings.
- set to *Branch Smoothing* to `1` and enabled `[X]` *Smooth Shading* in the modifier's settings
- add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier if needed

[image: the X with a skin modifier]

- if you want a sharper X shape, apply the *Skin* modifier, select the inner faces and scale them down or move the vertices to get the shape you want.

[image: applied skin modifier]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

found the solution, just cutting filling vertexes and taking time